# Need help optimizing C code for escaping a gas-filled hallway problem

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, logic

Problem:

Jojo who finished his vacation returned to his daily activities at the JLB office. The JLB office is unique because it only has one hallway from the entrance to the JLB room. Jojo who is working in the JLB room suddenly heard an emergency alarm sound and heard that there is a gas pipe leak that caused the only hallway to be contaminated by the gas.
Jojo must immediately get out of the JLB room to save himself. The gas is so poisonous that Jojo must hold his breath when he exits the JLB room. Fortunately there are several stairs in the hallway that connect the first floor with the second floor that is free of gas.
However, each of these stairs can only be used maximally once that is, to go up to the second floor or go down to the first floor. When Jojo is on the second floor, Jojo can exhale and breathe freely.
Can Jojo get out of the JLB office alive if Jojo optimize his
steps?

NOTE: In the beginning, Jojo stands in the first plot and his breath decreased every time he steps from one plot to another. His breath will not decreased while climbing stairs or down stairs.

Format Input:
There are T test cases.
Each testcase contains integers N and K which represent the
length of the hall and how long Jojo can hold his breath.
On the next line there are N numbers which contain either ‘0’ or ‘1’:

- ‘1’ indicates that there are stairs in the plot and
- ‘0’ indicates that there are no stairs in the plot.

Format Output:
T line with format “Case #X: ”, where X represents the testcase number then followed by “Alive” if Jojo can get out safely and “Dead” if not

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int longest(char arr[], int N);

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int N, k;
        scanf("%d %d", &N, &k);
        char arr[N+1];
        scanf("%s", arr);

        if (longest(arr, N) < k) {
            printf("Case #%d: Alive\n", i + 1);
        } else {
            printf("Case #%d: Dead\n", i + 1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int longest(char arr[], int N) {
    int longestt = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int firstStair = -1;
    int lastStair = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == '1') {
            if (firstStair == -1) firstStair = i;
            lastStair = i;
        }
    }

    if (firstStair != -1) longestt = firstStair;

    if (lastStair != -1 && N - lastStair - 1 > longestt) longestt = N - lastStair - 1;

    return longestt;
}
```

I don't know exactly what went wrong here but it was not accepted by the online judge, I'm guessing the problem might be if the amount of stairs are odd Jojo goes down from the last - 1 th stair

test case example:

```
4
9 3
001011010
10 4
0000100100
10 4
0001010000
10 4
0001001000
```

Expected output:

```
Case #1: Alive
Case #2: Dead
Case #3: Dead
Case #4: Alive
```

With my code I have matched these test cases

Note: the output doesn't need to come all at once it can be outputted once every test case

Comment: @Gerhard do I need to pay to have access to the solution?

Comment: When there are no stairs, your code for `longest` returns zero, but the distance that must be traversed on the first floor is `N`.